# Argparse "command not found"

Tags: python, argparse

With simple password (up to 10 characters) argpass works

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', '-password',dest='pwd',help='The password for authentication.')
args = parser.parse_args()

user = 'monitoring@domain.com'
pwd = args.pwd

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
conn.login(user,pwd)
```

But with complex password with 13 characters i'm getting

```
[1] 26160
bash: xxxxxxxx: command not found
```

(where xxxxxxxx are last 8 password characters)

```
script.py -password somepassword
```

Comment: Your password apparently has an `&` in it, and you aren't properly quoting it when you run the command. This is a shell issue, not a Python issue.

Comment: yes, it has &, i'll try removing it

Comment: If the password has a `&`, you can't remove it; you have to *quote* it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running something like

```
script.py -password foo&xxxxxxxx
```

which your shell parses as

```
script.py -password foo & xxxxxxxx
```

which results in running the command `script.py -password foo` in the background, then attempting to run the command `xxxxxxxx`. Quote the password.

```
script.py -password 'foo&xxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: just reset the password and removed & from it and it works now, thank you !!

Comment: There are other reasons why you might need to quote the password as a command-line argument; don't let shell syntax dictate what you can or can't use as a password. Use shell syntax to correctly use the password *you* choose.